# SQLCE invalid Algorithm specified error

Tags: sql-server-ce

Below code throws an 'Invalid Algorithm specified error'

**Code :**

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlCeConnection conn = DataHelper.GetConnection();
        {
            using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM <table>";
                SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
                dataTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }
        return dataTable;
```

Error Message 
Invalid algorithm specified. -    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)

**Stack Trace** 
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)

Comment: Please post your entire connection string.

Comment: Is that the actual sql statement?